# Can I access to android hardware from the outside?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I am writing a middleware that collects data from several sensors. I want to get data even from android device, reading the value from their sensor such as gps.

How can I get the data from these device? Is it possible from the outside to have the access to the android hardware of the device?

Comment: You can use Bluetooth or wifi.

Comment: You'd have to write some app/service that collects the data and sends it through your preferred channel (bluetooth, wifi, ...), to send it to your middleware. More info on sensors : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the data from these device?

Write an app that runs on the device, gathers the sensor data, and publishes it in some fashion where you can pick up the data from the "outside" (WiFiDirect, Bluetooth, Internet/local WiFi network, etc.).

> Is it possible from the outside to have the access to the android hardware of the device?

Only by means of talking to some program running on the device.

Comment: ok I will write an app that runs on the device, reads the value of the sensor that I need, and then? How can I transfer these data to my middleware? I have to use http put?

Comment: @MarioLepore: "How can I transfer these data to my middleware?" -- ask the person who wrote your "middleware" what protocols it supports, choose one, and use it. I did not write your "middleware" and therefore have no idea what it supports.